# How can I add a progress dialog in AsyncTask with minimum loading time (2sec)

Tags: android

When user clicks button, will go to Activity B from Activity A.
However, since in Activity B, data will be downloaded from Internet, I would like to add a progress dialog. 
Sometimes, the connection will be very fast, less than one second and sometimes will be more than 5 seconds.
If the progress dialog shows <1 sec, I think it is very bad for user experience.
So, I would like to add a minimum loading time, for example, 2 seconds.
That means even the loading time is less than 2 seconds, the progress dialog will also at least show 2 seconds.
Is there any ways to do so?

Comment: If you don't know at the start of the `AsyncTask` the duration of the operation then you can't set a minimum  loading time. If the actual time will only be seen at the end then obviously you'll need to wait and show the dialog no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Below Code. Pass Time and Object of your Dialog here.

```
public void timerDelayRemoveDialog(long time, final Dialog d){
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {           
        public void run() {                
            d.dismiss();         
        }
    }, time); 
}
```

**EDITED**

you can Use this Sample Code :

```
class LoginProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(4000);  // Do your real work here
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Boolean.TRUE;   // Return your real result here
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    showDialog(AUTHORIZING_DIALOG);
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    // result is the value returned from doInBackground
    removeDialog(AUTHORIZING_DIALOG);
    Intent i = new Intent(HelloAndroid.this, LandingActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: where should I call this function?

Comment: The AsyncTask is in Activity A or Activity B??

Comment: And where is the timerDelayRemoveDialog called??

Comment: I think According to your Problem it will be in Activity A Where you are Downloading from internet After got to Activity B.

Comment: But if I want to call it in Activity B, how can I do it? Since the Activity A will finish() and I would like all data to be loaded in Activity B. Also, The Thread.sleep(4000) should be deleted when I want to do the real work?

Comment: then you should call your downloading part in Activity B and Display it as you want. and also then you have to call asynctask in Activity B. if you want to Use Asynctask then you will no need to use timerDelayRemoveDialog Method in your code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (worked well):

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    long timestamp1;
    long timestamp2;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(YOUR_CONTEXT);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.show();

        timestamp1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //doSomething ...

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        //doSomething ...

        timestamp2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeDifference = timestamp2 - timestamp1;

        if (timeDifference >= 2000) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, 2000 - timeDifference);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version. Using SystemClock does not require try catch block.
`ParentActivity.this` is the context where Task is executed.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.SystemClock;

protected class Task extends AsyncTask< String, Void, String >
{
    private ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog( ParentActivity.this );

    private long mTaskStartTimeMills;

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        mTaskStartTimeMills = System.currentTimeMillis();

        mDialog.setMessage( "Loading.." );
        mDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground( String... arg )
    {
        // TODO
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute( String json )
    {
        final long timeToWait = 1000 - ( System.currentTimeMillis() - mTaskStartTimeMills );

        if ( timeToWait > 0 )
        {
            SystemClock.sleep( timeToWait );
        }

        mDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this may helps you

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            ProgressDialog mDialog;
            ArrayList<String> files;            
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyMainAct.this);
                mDialog.setMessage("Loading");
                mDialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          //   do your work here 
                Log.i("Share Media MyMainAct", " newFiles is called path is - " + path +"/" + spndirectory.getSelectedItem().toString());               
                files = getFiles(path + "/" + spndirectory.getSelectedItem().toString());               
                return null;
            }           
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result){              
                if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()){
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
                setFileAdapter(files);
            }
        }.execute();
```