# How to make a task (progressDialog) loading at least 2sec in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add a progress dialog in AsyncTask with minimum loading time (2sec)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402788/how-can-i-add-a-progress-dialog-in-asynctask-with-minimum-loading-time-2sec)

I would like to load something from Internet and config the camera.
If the loading time is too short, it is not good for users.
So, I want to load at least 2 sec. 
How to do it?

Comment: Why it's not good for the users? The faster the better in my mind.

Comment: If it shows 0.5sec, and dismiss, I think it is not good. I want to make it really loading something in user point of view.

Answer (score 2):

get timestamp when this dialog was showed and compare it with the timestamp when you want to finish it. If 2 seconds passed, dismiss it, else create a thread and run it after x milliseconds (2000 - (timestamp2 - timestamp1)) and dismiss it after this thread ends.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
try {
  Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

It will be better if you do it inside an AsyncTask.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For a run once timing event i would recooment using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). 
Something like this

```
 Handler h= new Handler();
 h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
      //Do your stuff here         
  }}, 2000);
```